# Find unique values across a character string

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a column in a Dataframe (first column) in R as shown below. It consists of numerical values as shown in the first column (i.e. Actual Column), which consists of duplicate values as well. I need a resultant column as shown below so as to remove duplicates and give only the unique values

```
Actual Column           Resultant Column
3232, 3232              3232  
3725, 3725              3725
3725, 3725, 4687        3275, 4687
```

Comment: `sapply(df$"Actual Column", function(x) paste(unique(strsplit(x, ", ")[[1]]), collapse=", "))` ?

Comment: Tried the above command @chinsoon12 , it's not working

Comment: can you `dput` your actual data? i am assuming that your Actual Column is a character vector

Comment: > dput(test1)
structure(list(Actual_column = c("[3232, 3232, 3232, 3232, 3232, 3232, 3232, 3232]", 
"[3725, 3725]", "[5383, 5383]", "[1932, 1932]", "[559, 2372]", 
"[2372, 2372]", "[2754, 2754, 2754, 2754, 2754, 2387, 2387]", 
"[2754, 2754, 2754, 2754, 2754]", "[2387, 2387]", "[3748, 3748]"
)), .Names = "Actual_column", row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Try `sapply(strsplit(trimws(gsub('\\D+', ' ', df$Actual_column)), ' '), function(i) paste(unique(i), collapse = ', '))`. Also don't post data in comments. Edit your question and add it there

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, It works